# How can I have a link at the end of an angular material autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I am trying to have a link at the end of an angular material autocomplete. I need the link to always be visible. I found a workaround by creating a directive that kind of hijack the "md-not-found" element and always shows it. Here is an example of what it looks like :

https://plnkr.co/edit/5tfjYfrT59xx47k3Idke?p=preview

On first focus, it looks exactly like what I'm trying to achieve. The link "Create User" appears after all the results. Then after a search, let's say "a", the autocomplete results box shrink down to 1 element and never get back to full height.

How can I fix this behaviour ? Or is there another way to do what I am trying to do ?

Please keep in mind that this is just an example, I am not really trying to create users on the fly like that.

Thank you very much.

Here is the directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').directive('notFoundAlwaysVisible', notFoundAlwaysVisible)

    notFoundAlwaysVisible.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

    function notFoundAlwaysVisible($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^mdAutocomplete',            
            replace: true,
            template: '',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
                parentCtrl.notFoundVisible = function () { return true; }
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is my autocomplete element with the new directive on it :

```
<md-autocomplete md-no-cache="true" 
                    not-found-always-visible
                    md-selected-item="ctrl.item" 
                    md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" 
                    md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                    md-item-text="item.Name" 
                    md-min-length="0" 
                    md-floating-label="Username" 
                    md-select-on-match="true"
                    md-match-case-insensitive="true">
      <md-item-template>
        <div>
          <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{ item.Name }}</span>
        </div>
      </md-item-template>
      <md-not-found>
        <a href="#">Create User {{ ctrl.searchText }}</a>
      </md-not-found>
    </md-autocomplete>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer as yet, but I can tell you *why* it's happening. The autocomplete uses an `md-virtual-repeat-container` for the results box. When the `md-autocomplete` controller's function `notFoundVisible` returns true (as is being forced by your directive), a CSS class of `md-not-found` is applied to the container. That class, sets a height of 48px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if [this](http://codepen.io/webservconsultant/pen/NrWVjb) helps . You can add your link at the end of the results and have its own stylesheet for that link.

```
<md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in (ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText).concat(ctrl.footerOption))" 
       md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0" placeholder="What is your favorite US state?"  md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
        <md-item-template>
         <div ng-class="{fixed:item.isFooter}">
           <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
          </div>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
          No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
          <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
        </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
```

You can track the footer like this,

```
function selectedItemChange(item) {
      if (item) {
        if (item.isFooter)
           $log.info('footer selected, creating a new'  + JSON.stringify(item));           
        else           
          $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));           
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you add your footer to the results list, then it will use the correct style.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you handle the click event ? in the md-selected-item-change ?

Comment: Edited above answer